# Accessing virtual hosts from other computers – xip.io alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtualhost, saucelabs, rack-pow, xip.io

> Sometimes you need to access your (Pow) virtual hosts from another computer on your local network — for example, when testing your application on a mobile device or from a Windows or Linux VM.

So far I've been using [`pow`](http://pow.cx/) and [xip.io](http://xip.io/) seems to be the *de facto* way to [access virtual hosts from other computers](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.1.5).

Today I needed to test a hotfix on Internet Explorer, on a Windows machine, using [saucelabs.com](https://saucelabs.com), and in this scenario xip.io doesn't work anymore.

The Pow User's Manual suggests `showoff-io` as an alternative – *the easiest way to share localhost over the web* – but it seems that this one has turned commercial, revamped as [forwardhq.com](https://forwardhq.com/).

Are there any free alternatives to xip.io that work with testing platforms like Sauce Labs?

Comment: I also would love a free alternative to ForwardHQ. I'd be willing to pay a one-time fee for ForwardHQ since I use it on occasion, but I don't want to pay monthly for a service I rarely use.

Comment: Try [Burrow.io](https://burrow.io). The free plan lets you create one HTTP tunnel, and you don't need to install anything. After creating the tunnel through the web interface, all you have to do is paste a CURL command on your terminal and you get magically connected. I think I will add this as an answer.

Comment: There's also [nip.io](http://nip.io/), a blatant rip-off of xip.io which claims to work better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**ngrok.com**](https://ngrok.com/) is a great alternative too.
Simple Go binary, and it proxies both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: I've been using ngrok for a long time and highly recommend it. Its author is also very responsive and passionate about the project.

Answer (score 3):

I have used [proxylocal](http://proxylocal.com/) successfully with Sauce Labs and it's free with [source](https://github.com/proxylocal/proxylocal-gem) available on Github.

I unfortunately found ForwardHQ frequently disconnected but proxylocal has been solid so far.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Burrow.io](https://burrow.io). The free plan lets you create one HTTP tunnel, and you don't need to install anything. After creating the tunnel through the web interface, all you have to do is paste a CURL command on your terminal and you get magically connected.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more tool similar to proxylocal - [localtunnel](http://localtunnel.me/) (it's github link - https://github.com/defunctzombie/localtunnel )